# Modify the predominant color of an Image

Tags: canvas, graphics, colors

Given an RGB value and an Image. What I wanna to achieve is to color the Image using the RGB input and I wanna replace the predominant color of the image with my RGB value.
What is the easiest way to achieve this ?

Comment: Find out what the predominant color is, then replace every pixel of that color with the input color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a script like colorThief to get the dominant color from an image:

https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief

Then use this kind of code to replace the predominant color with your desired color

This is **untested** code...some tweaking might be required:

```
function recolor(image,predominantRed,predominantGreen,predominantBlue){

    // get the image dimensions
    var w=image.width;
    var h=image.height;

    // set the canvas dimensions to the image dimensions
    canvas.width=w;
    canvas.height=h;

    // draw the image to the canvas
    context.drawImage(image,0,0);

    // get the canvas' pixel array
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
    var data = imageData.data;

    // loop through the pixel array
    // replace any predominant color with your new color
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i+=4) {
        var red=data[i];
        var green=data[i+1];
        var blue=data[i+2];
        if(red==predominantRed 
              && green==predominantGreen
              && blue==predominantBlue){
            data[i]  = yourRed;
            data[i+1]= yourGreen;
            data[i+2]= yourBlue;
        }
    }

    // put the modified pixels back on the canvas
    context.putImageData(imageData, x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a statistic by looping through the pixel array buffer and count instances of each color.

Then you pick the instance with highest count.

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/KwYCY/)**

One way of doing this is as follows (not optimized but for sake of example):

```
var rgb = {};

/// get image buffer

for(var i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {

    /// get components
    r = buffer[i];
    g = buffer[i + 1];
    b = buffer[i + 2];

    /// create a key based on components to identify color
    color = [r,g,b].join();

    /// count this color
    rgb[color] = (rgb[color] || 0) + 1;
}
```

This will produce an object with all existing colors and the count of each. So next step is to find the one with highest count:

```
function getDominantColor() {

    var max = -1,                /// max count
        color = null,            /// the actual color
        keys = Object.keys(rgb), /// get keys of rgb object
        len = keys.length,       /// cache length
        v,                       /// value (color) based on key
        i = 0;

    for(;i < len; i++) {

        /// get count for this key
        v = rgb[keys[i]];

        /// if higher than previous, replace with this as max
        if (v > max) {
            max = v;
            color = keys[i];
        }
    }

    /// convert string to array
    color = color.split(',');

    /// return array with integer values
    return [parseInt(color[0], 10),
            parseInt(color[1], 10),
            parseInt(color[2], 10)]
}
```

Now you can go through the pixel buffer again and replace the colors with a new one:

```
for(i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
    r = buffer[i];
    g = buffer[i + 1];
    b = buffer[i + 2];

    if (r === color[0] &&
        g === color[1] &&
        b === color[2]) {

        /// set new color, red here for example
        buffer[i] = 255;
        buffer[i + 1] = 0;
        buffer[i + 2] = 0;
    }
}
```

Things to note: A dominant color does not necessarily have to be *visually* dominant. There can be many colors that looks similar but aren't. So the way to solve this is to implement *tolerance* for the color you want to replace if this is what you secondary goal is.